# can't assign PORTD a variable value on PIC18F

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, gpio

I'm using the following code to test some GPIO while I mess around with the PIC18F45K20 demo board. I realised something was strange when I couldn't increment a value and see it reflected on the LEDs after writing it to the port. Any idea why that is? I'm using the C18 compiler with MPLABX  IDE v3.05

Using aPICkit3 with this demo kit: http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=dm164130-4

```
#pragma config FOSC = INTIO67   
#pragma config WDTEN = OFF, LVP = OFF   

#define TIMER T0CON

#include "p18f45k20.h"   

void delay();   

void delay() {      
   int counter = 0;   
   for (counter = 0; counter<1000; counter++);    
}   
void main(void) {     

   unsigned char d = 0;   

   TRISD = 0; // all bits of portd are set 0 as output      
   PORTD = 0; // deactivate all led's   

   while (1) {    

       d++;

       PORTD = d;

       delay();        

   }       
}
```

Comment: Try writing to `LATD` instead of `PORTD` and also make your delay a lot slower.

Comment: Where do you reset d when it reaches the maximum 255? If you try assigning a number >255 to a port, it'll cause an error (it is only an 8-bit port, is it not?)

Comment: @derstrom8 unsigned char is an 8-bit variable. It will overflow and wrap around.

Comment: Hmm, I knew it was an 8-bit variable, but I guess I forgot it wraps automatically =P

Comment: I added an overflow reset just in case, made no difference. As Matt said, the 8 bit unsigned char should wrap around when it overflows.

Answer (score 1):

On PICs, you read from PORT and write to LAT. Replace PORTD with LATD. It's also not a bad idea to declare `counter` as `volatile int counter = 0;`. Don't forget `{}` after `for(counter = 0; counter<1000; counter++)`.

Comment: Replaced PORTD with LATD, still no luck. Also, seems strange that I can write a hex value to PORTD and see it output if it's only for reading.

Comment: @Sensors It's best practice to write to LAT and read from PORT.  It's due to the history of PICs.  Originally, PORT was used for both reading and writing.  So-called "Read-Modify-Write" errors were common, so Microchip created the LAT registers for writing.  The ability to write to PORT was retained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Sensors I have no idea what demo board you have. Post the disassembly. Do you have a PICKit or ICD?

Comment: I've updated the post with a link to the demo board I'm using. Also using a PICkit3 to program.

Comment: @MattYoung for delays, you do not need the brackets after your for loop. A semicolon is sufficient.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to declare int counter as volatile. It's possible that the compiler is optimizing your delay loop out; volatile may prevent that from happening. Another possibility is to clear the watchdog timer every loop, something that the compiler should definitely not optimize out. You might also try clearing TRISE.PSPMODE manually; if it's set, it could override the D port. Manual says it's zero by default, but stranger things have happened.

Comment: @derstrom8 I've seen enough stupid with Microchip compilers to not leave anything to chance.

Comment: @MattYoung I have never had an issue, I've tried Hi-Tech and C18. Have not tried Mikro-C though.

Comment: What's the FOSC speed? If it's 8MHz with a 4x PLL active, 32MHz = 8MIPS. One iteration of the "delay" could be as little as 1100 or so instructions, and since each instruction takes 1/8MIPS to execute, or 0.0001375s - 255 values written to a port at this rate only takes up 35mS - just at the limit of human [persistence of vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision).